# Callback de upload de arquivos com o Multer - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

Olá alguém já utilizou o multer(modulo do express/nodeJS) para realizar uploads de arquivos? Se sim como conseguiu capturar os eventos de callbacks(onFileUploadStart e onFileUploadComplete) ? Teoricamente estou utilizando corretamente mas em momento algum os eventos são chamadas...

Código de exemplo:

```
'use strict';
//DEFINO AS DEPENDENCIAS
var express = require('express');
var multer = require('multer');
var uploadRealizado = false;
var servidor = express();


//CONFIGURO O MULTER NA INSTANCIA DO EXPRESS(no caso nosso servidor)
var upload = multer({
    dest: './testeUpload/',
    rename: function(nomeCampo, nomeArquivo) {
        return nomeArquivo+Date.now();
    },
    onFileUploadStart: function(arquivo) {
        console.log('COMEÇOU O UPLOAD');        
    },
    onFileUploadComplete: function (arquivo) {
        console.log('TERMINOU O UPLOAD');       
        uploadRealizado = true;
    }
});

//APLICANDO AS ROTAS
servidor.get('/', function(requisicao, resposta) {
    resposta.sendfile('./home.html');
});

servidor.post('/api/photo', upload.single('avatar'), function(requisicao, resposta) {
    console.log('STATUS UPLOAD' + uploadRealizado);
    console.log('ARQUIVOS', requisicao.file | requisicao.files);
    if (uploadRealizado) {              
        resposta.send('foto enviada');
    }
    resposta.send('foto não enviada');
});


//INICIO O SERVIDOR
servidor.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('servidor rodando na porta 3000');
});
```

Att,

Comment: Não vejo essas [callbacks na documentação](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) podes apontar onde viste que o multer tem callbacks?

Comment: então... vi em quase toda tutorial que envolve Multer... :

https://codeforgeek.com/2014/11/file-uploads-using-node-js/

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26702869/multer-not-uploading-files-when-i-include-logic-in-onfileuploadstart-nodejs

*Como documentação nem sempre é um fortes dos módulos de nodeJS acabei indo com a maioria

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olha, vou tentar ajudar apenas traduzindo essa resposta [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32045027/multer-callbacks-not-working.).

Parece que o uso foi alterado ao longo do tempo. Atualmente, multer construtor só aceita opções seguintes (https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#multer-opts):

dest ou storage - Onde para armazenar os arquivos
 fileFilter - Função para controlar quais arquivos são aceitos
 limits - Limites dos dados enviados
Assim, por exemplo a mudança de nome deve ser resolvido por meio da configuração de armazenamento adequado (https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#storage).

var storage = multer.diskStorage({ destination: function (req, file, cb) { cb(null, '/tmp/my-uploads'); // Absolute path. Folder must exist, will not be created for you. }, filename: function (req, file, cb) { cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now()); } }) var upload = multer({ storage: storage }); app.post('/profile', upload.single('fieldname'), function (req, res, next) { // req.body contains the text fields }); 
O fieldname deve coincidir com o nome do campo no corpo da solicitação. Ou seja, em caso de HTML formulário post, o nome da entrada elemento formulário de upload.

Também dê uma olhada para outras funções de middleware como array e fields - https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#single-fieldname que fornecem aa pouca funcionalidade diferente.

Além disso, você pode estar interessado nos limites (https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#limits) e filtro de arquivo (https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#filefilter)

E também - fonte é a única fonte da verdade - tem uma espiada (https://github.com/expressjs/multer/blob/master/index.js)